# Commerce Cloud Controller Authentication

Tags: rest-api, controller, oauth2, authentication, commerce-cloud

I did a controller inside commerce cloud in order to update the order from the external Order Management Service.

Then controller inside the Commerce Cloud will receive the order details by a POST method and save the updates in the order accordingly.

The problem is that I am not able to send a request by an external resource. For any request I receive a result:

```
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <title>401 - Authorization Required.</title>
    <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="/waroot/style.css">
</head>
```

I am sending the request to get the token in https://account.demandware.com/dwsso/oauth2/access_token and with the proper token sending the request with the token for the resource location, following the example given in https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2Fcontent%2Fb2c_commerce%2Ftopics%2Fsearch_engine_optimization%2Fb2c_digital_url_syntax_without_seo.html for example: https://localhost/on/demandware.store/Sites-SiteGenesis-Site/default/Hello-World

I tried two different controllers:

```
server.post('Test', function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        Transaction.wrap(function () {
            // Some logic
        });
    } catch(e) {
        Logger.error('Exception "{0}"" .', e.message);
    }
    next();
});
```

and also a more simple aproach:

```
exports.Test = function(){
    response.getWriter().println('Hello World!');
};
exports.Test.public = true;
```

But no matter what I do I always receive the 401 - Authorization Required response.

Is there something wrong in the authentication process, controller or my resource location that I should be changing to permit the request from an third-party system to access my controller?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to come from the fact that you're not returning anything in your controller.

Assuming you want to return JSON data, the **res** (response) argument passed to your **Test** function should solve the problem. Try this inside the function:

```
res.json({
    // Javascript object here    
});

return next();
```

The **json()** method of the **res** object should build and output JSON data when your controller function is called.

Have a look at the official doc for more info on the methods available for the **response** object in order to format the controller output.